# MongoDB replicaset with one node left

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I am designing an application which can run on up to 40 different servers. 
The application stores some data in a DB. It needs to be synced acros those 40 servers but also needs to be able to run completely standalone. 
If I could get notifications when the DB is updated that would be nice.

My first idea was to use a MongoDB replicaset. The new changestream would notify me of changes and all would be perfectly in sync.

After doing some research I learned that I will have dificulty running a server on its own (in case all the others are down). There will be no majority to vote for a primary DB.

Is there a different way I could set things up that WILL work both standalone and in a network with 40 nodes?

Comment: Couch may be a better fit for the job. Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#non-voting-members. The hard limit for repset is 50 members, but only 7 are voting ones with priority >0.

Comment: @AlexBlex It would run on node.js, so the limit for number of nodes would be > 50. But the 7 voting members is indeed one of the reasons this would not work.

Comment: The interesting part of the use case is, if each of those 40 servers went standalone for a period of time (day, week). When they all discover each other again to sync, which of the 40 servers are the source of truth for data changes ? perhaps there are some missing information on the case that needs elaboration.